# Conversion from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I need to upgrade/convert a Pyqt4 application to Pyqt5. It works fine when run using Pyqt4 and gives the desired result as shown in the screenshot attached, but the same does not run on PyQt5 even after making the required changes. In the updated code, The menus do not connect and nothing happens on clicking them. 
Please help me if i am missing something.

This is the UI.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1192, 794)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/Main_UI/icons/icons/icon-main.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1201, 771))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.gridLayout_6 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_6.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_6"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_6)
        self.mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.mdiArea.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mdiArea"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1192, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuSpatial_Analyst = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuSpatial_Analyst.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuSpatial_Analyst"))
        self.menuTool2 = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuTool2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuTool2"))
        self.menuTool3 = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuTool3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuTool3"))
        self.menuHelp = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuHelp"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.menuSpatial_Analyst)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.menuTool2)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.menuTool3)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.menuHelp)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Toolbox", None))
        self.menuSpatial_Analyst.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Tool1", None))
        self.menuTool2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Tool2", None))
        self.menuTool3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Tool3", None))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help", None))

import resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the Integration.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import os
import thread
import frmParent_Form
import Scripts.Zonal_Stat.Qt_ZoneStat as Qt_ZoneStat
import Scripts.Tabulate_Threading.UI_Func_Integrate as UI_Func_Integrate
import Scripts.Nearby.Join_NearbyFGDB as Join_NearbyFGDB
import Scripts.MakeThematic.UI_Func_Integrate as makeThem


class MyDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow,frmParent_Form.Ui_MainWindow):
    btn_added_Tool1=False
    btn_added_Tool2=False
    btn_added_Tool3=False
    btn_added_Help=False

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.subwindow=None
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('cleanlooks'))
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())  
        self.activeMenu=""
        self.menubar.triggered.connect(self.setUIForMenu)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenuBar {
                background-color: rgb(117, 161, 216);
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }

            QMenuBar::item {
                background-color: rgb(117, 161, 216);
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
            }

            QMenuBar::item::selected {
                background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);
            }

            QMenu {
                background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
                border: 1px solid #000;           
            }

            QMenu::item::selected {
                background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);
            }
        """)        

    def setUIForMenu(self):
        mdi_dimension=self.mdiArea.frameGeometry()
        self.widthDesktop  = mdi_dimension.width()         
        self.heightDesktop = mdi_dimension.height()     

        test=self.menubar.activeAction()
        strMenu= test.text()
        if strMenu=="Tool1" and self.activeMenu!="Tool1":
            self.activeMenu="Tool1"
            self.Tool1()
        elif strMenu=="Tool2" and self.activeMenu!="Tool2":
            self.activeMenu="Tool2"
            self.Tool2()
        elif strMenu=="Tool3" and self.activeMenu!="Tool3":
            self.activeMenu="Tool3"
            self.Tool3()
        elif strMenu=="Help":
            self.activeMenu="Help" 
            self.help()



    def Tool3(self):
        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False   

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

        if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3:
            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()

        if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3:

            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=True       


    def Tool2(self):
        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False   

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

        if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2:
            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()


            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=True   



    def Tool1(self):

        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False
        MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=False

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    

        if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1:
            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()

        if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1:
            widget=QWidget()
            #
            self.btn_ZonalStat = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.btn_ZonalStat.setText("Zonal Stat")
            self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_ZonalStat,0,0,1,5)
            self.btn_ZonalStat.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
            self.btn_ZonalStat.clicked.connect(self.Add_Subwindow)
            #
            self.btn_TabulateArea =QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.btn_TabulateArea.setText("Tabulate Area")
            self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_TabulateArea,1,0,1,5)
            self.btn_TabulateArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
            self.btn_TabulateArea.clicked.connect(self.Add_TabulateWindow)
            #
            self.btn_NearBy = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.btn_NearBy.setText("Nearby (Distance Computation)")
            self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_NearBy,2,0,1,5)
            self.btn_NearBy.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
            self.btn_NearBy.clicked.connect(self.Add_NearbyWindow)
            #
            self.MakeThem = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.MakeThem.setText("Make Thematic")
            self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.MakeThem,3,0,1,5)
            self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(widget,4,0,10,10)
            self.MakeThem.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
            self.MakeThem.clicked.connect(self.Add_MakeThemWindow)
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=True   



    def help(self):

        foldPath=os.getcwd()+"\\help\\"
        path=str(os.path.join(foldPath, "Toolbox-Chm.chm"))
        thread.start_new_thread(os.system, (r"KeyHH.exe -MyHelp -#klink 'Toolbox'           "+path,))   

    def check_position(self, y, width, height, sub_window): 
        from random import randint     
        sub_window.move(int(self.widthDesktop/2)-int(width/2), int(self.heightDesktop/2)-int(height/2))     
        print("Sub Window Moved")    

    def Add_Subwindow(self):

        for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

        self.btn_ZonalStat.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);")

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

        widget = Qt_ZoneStat.MyDialog()
        self.subwindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
        self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
        self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

        widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
        widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

        self.connect(widget,QtCore.SIGNAL('Progres_Counter_1'),self.test)
        widget.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show()    

    def Add_TabulateWindow(self):

        for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

        self.btn_TabulateArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);") 
        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    
        widget = UI_Func_Integrate.MyDialog()
        self.subwindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea)self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)  
        self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
        widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()  
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

        self.connect(widget,QtCore.SIGNAL('Progres_Counter_1'),self.test)
        widget.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show() 

    def Add_NearbyWindow(self):

        for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

        self.btn_NearBy.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);")       

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    
        widget = Join_NearbyFGDB.MyDialog()
        self.subwindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
        self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
        self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)  
        self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)   
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
        widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

        self.connect(widget,QtCore.SIGNAL('Progres_Counter_1'),self.test)
        widget.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show()  

    def Add_MakeThemWindow(self):

        for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
            self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

        self.MakeThem.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);") 

        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    

        self.subwindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
        widget = makeThem.MyDialog()
        self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
        self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30) 

        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

        widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
        widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()

        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show()
        self.connect(widget,QtCore.SIGNAL('Progres_Counter_1'),self.test)



    def test(self):
        if self.subwindow!=None:
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

if __name__ == '__main__':# if we're running file directly and not importing it
try:
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp = MyDialog()
   myapp.show()
   app.exec_()   
except:
   print (str(sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

[image: The image here shows how the application works, Each menu option has sub menus as buttons which opens a new tool window]

The image here shows how the application works, Each menu option has sub menus as buttons which opens a new tool window.

I have updated the Ui.py with the necessary changes, i.e changed the module wherever required.This is the updated PyQt5 Integration.py

```
    class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,frmParent_Form.Ui_MainWindow):
        Progres_Counter_1= pyqtSignal()
        btn_added_Tool1=False
        btn_added_Tool2=False
        btn_added_Tool3=False
        btn_added_Help=False

        def __init__(self):
            super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
            self.subwindow=None
            QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('cleanlooks'))
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.setFixedSize(self.size())  
            self.activeMenu=""
            self.menubar.triggered.connect(self.setUIForMenu)
            self.setStyleSheet("""
                QMenuBar {
                    background-color: rgb(117, 161, 216);
                    color: rgb(255,255,255);
                    border: 1px solid #000;
                }

                QMenuBar::item {
                    background-color: rgb(117, 161, 216);
                    color: rgb(255,255,255);
                }

                QMenuBar::item::selected {
                    background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);
                }

                QMenu {
                    background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
                    color: rgb(255,255,255);
                    border: 1px solid #000;           
                }

                QMenu::item::selected {
                    background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);
                }
            """)        

        def setUIForMenu(self):
            mdi_dimension=self.mdiArea.frameGeometry()
            self.widthDesktop  = mdi_dimension.width()         
            self.heightDesktop = mdi_dimension.height()     

            test=self.menubar.activeAction()
            strMenu= test.text()
            if strMenu=="Tool1" and self.activeMenu!="Tool1":
                self.activeMenu="Tool1"
                self.Tool1()
            elif strMenu=="Tool2" and self.activeMenu!="Tool2":
                self.activeMenu="Tool2"
                self.Tool2()
            elif strMenu=="Tool3" and self.activeMenu!="Tool3":
                self.activeMenu="Tool3"
                self.Tool3()
            elif strMenu=="Help":
                self.activeMenu="Help" 
                self.help()



        def Tool3(self):
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False   

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3:
                for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()

            if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3:

                MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=True       


        def Tool2(self):
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False   

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2:
                for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()


                MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=True   



        def Tool1(self):

            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool3=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Miscellaneous=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Help=False
            MyDialog.btn_added_Tool2=False

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    

            if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1:
                for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count())): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()

            if not MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1:
                #
                widget=QWidget()
                self.btn_ZonalStat = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
                self.btn_ZonalStat.setText("Zonal Stat")
                self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_ZonalStat,0,0,1,5)
                self.btn_ZonalStat.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
                self.btn_ZonalStat.clicked.connect(self.Add_Subwindow)
                #
                self.btn_TabulateArea = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
                self.btn_TabulateArea.setText("Tabulate Area")
                self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_TabulateArea,1,0,1,5)
                self.btn_TabulateArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
                self.btn_TabulateArea.clicked.connect(self.Add_TabulateWindow)
                #
                self.btn_NearBy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
                self.btn_NearBy.setText("Nearby (Distance Computation)")
                self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.btn_NearBy,2,0,1,5)
                self.btn_NearBy.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
                self.btn_NearBy.clicked.connect(self.Add_NearbyWindow)
                #
                self.MakeThem = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
                self.MakeThem.setText("Make Thematic")
                self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.MakeThem,3,0,1,5)
                self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(widget,4,0,10,10)
                self.MakeThem.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
                self.MakeThem.clicked.connect(self.Add_MakeThemWindow)
                MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1=True   



        def help(self):
            #os.system(r"KeyHH.exe -MyHelp -#klink 'Zonal Stats' C:\Users\nkandpal\Desktop\package\ITool.chm::Zonal Stats")    
            foldPath=os.getcwd()+"\\help\\"
            path=str(os.path.join(foldPath, "Toolbox-Chm.chm"))
            _thread.start_new_thread(os.system, (r"KeyHH.exe -MyHelp -#klink 'Toolbox' "+path,))   

        def check_position(self, y, width, height, sub_window): 
            from random import randint     
            sub_window.move(int(self.widthDesktop/2)-int(width/2), int(self.heightDesktop/2)-int(height/2))     
            print("Sub Window Moved")    

        def Add_Subwindow(self):

            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

            self.btn_ZonalStat.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);")

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            widget = Qt_ZoneStat.MyDialog()
            self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
            self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
            self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)   
            #self.subwindow.setWindowTitle("GeoHazzard Aggregation")
            self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
            widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
            self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

            self.widget.Progres_Counter_1.connect(self.test)
            widget.show()
            self.subwindow.show()
            self.subwindow.widget().show()    

        def Add_TabulateWindow(self):

            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

            self.btn_TabulateArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);") 
            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    
            widget = UI_Func_Integrate.MyDialog()
            self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
            self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
            self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)   
            #self.subwindow.setWindowTitle("GeoHazzard Aggregation")
            self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
            widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
            self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

            self.widget.Progres_Counter_1.connect(self.test)
            widget.show()
            self.subwindow.show()
            self.subwindow.widget().show() 

        def Add_NearbyWindow(self):

            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

            self.btn_NearBy.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);")       

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    
            widget = Join_NearbyFGDB.MyDialog()
            self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
            self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
            #val= widget.size().height()
            self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)   
            self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
            widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
            self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

            self.widget.Progres_Counter_1.connect(self.test)
            widget.show()
            self.subwindow.show()
            self.subwindow.widget().show()  

        def Add_MakeThemWindow(self):

            for i in reversed(range(self.gridLayout_6.count()-1)): 
                self.gridLayout_6.itemAt(i).widget().setStyleSheet("background-color: white")   

            self.MakeThem.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 112, 216);color: rgb(255,255,255);") 

            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)    

            self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self.mdiArea) 
            widget = makeThem.MyDialog()
            self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)  
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
            self.subwindow.setFixedSize(widget.size().width()+10,widget.size().height()+30)   
            #self.subwindow.setWindowTitle("GeoHazzard Aggregation")

            self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)

            widget_position = self.subwindow.pos()
            widget_dimensions = self.subwindow.frameGeometry()
            self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=self.subwindow)   

            self.subwindow.show()
            self.subwindow.widget().show()
            self.widget.Progres_Counter_1.connect(self.test)



        def test(self):
            if self.subwindow!=None:
                self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.subwindow)

    if __name__ == '__main__':# if we're running file directly and not importing it
        try:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            myapp = MyDialog()
            myapp.show()
            app.exec_()   
        except:
            print (str(sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You really should not edit files generated with pyuic, *never*. Those files should only be used as imported modules as explained in the guide about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). To port ui files to Qt5 you have to run `pyuic5` to generate the new updated files. Don't do that by hand.

Comment: @eyllanesc The menus do not connect and nothing happens on clicking them

Comment: 1) change `QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)` to `QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)`

Comment: @eyllanesc It still does not make any difference

Comment: @ManishaShrivastava It does have consequences: it eliminates silent errors. According to your code, your class inherits from QMainWindow but you call the constructor of QDialog. Do you think that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the actions not working is that you are using a very wrong method to "get" them.

I don't know if the `setUIForMenu()` worked when you were using PyQt4 (I don't believe it should have, but its behavior could have been different according to the platform), but you certainly should not use [`activeAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#activeAction):

> Returns the **currently highlighted** action, or nullptr if no action is currently highlighted.

Clearly, that's not what you need for your purpose, but, most importantly, all that is completely unnecessary: [`QMenuBar.triggered()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#triggered) already returns the action that has been triggered.

```
    def setUIForMenu(self, action):
        strMenu = action.menu().title()
```

---

Besides that, there are a lot of problems in your question.

- First of all, as already pointed out in comments, files generated with `pyuic` should **NEVER** be modified. Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand the correct ways to use those files.
- For the reason above, if you want to migrate to Qt5, you should obviously not edit those files by hand, but just use the correct version of pyuic (named `pyuic5`, usually) to build Qt5 compatible files. Then leave those files alone and *never* edit them, and only overwrite them with pyuic whenever you have to change their source ui files.
- Setting class attributes to store variables that should be those of an *instance* is just bad: all those `MyDialog.btn_added_Tool1 = ...` should be `self.btn_added_Tool1`, etc., since you are using them as instance attributes.
- Local imports should only be done when absolutely necessary and with absolute care: put the `from random import randint` along with the other imports at the beginning of the script.
- Always prefer "new" connect styling (`object.signal.connect(slot)`), as the "old" method of using `QtCore.SIGNAL` is almost always unnecessary and discouraged (also, AFAIK, in the latest PyQt5 versions `QtCore.SIGNAL` is not even available anymore).
- Setting an application-wide style should not happen in the `__init__` of a QWidget.
- In the `test` function you are removing the subwindow, but you're not setting the `subwindow` variable back to `None`.
- Using strings for object comparison is not a good idea: you might decide to change a menu/item text, the string could be localized, or the style might add a "&" mnemonic that's beyond your control; use the *object instances* instead (e.g.: `if action.menu() == self.menuTool2: ...`).
- Finally, be more consistent with name styling, and possibly follow the [Python style guide for code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (aka, PEP-8); most importantly, in your case, function names should not be capitalized; also, when equal signs are used for variable assignment, it's usually better to put spaces around them, as it improves readability.